# How do you prove for all $k$ in the integers, $2-5k$ can never be a perfect square?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, induction, square-numbers

Proving this for $k > 0$ is easy and intuitive, but I'm unsure how to proceed with the negative values for $k$. Should I use modular congruence somehow? Or can I prove this more simply? My gut said since it is for all integers, I should try proof by induction, but I have no idea where to go with that.

Answer (score 5):

Simply check that, mod $5$, $0^2, 1^2, 2^2, 3^2$, and $4^2$ are respectively $0,1,4,4$, and $1$. Meanwhile $2-5k\equiv 2$.

Comment: I understand why 2−5k≡2, but could you explain why I need to check 0 through 4 mod 5? I think I'm not understanding some simple middle step

Comment: Suppose $x^2=2-5k$. Then $x^2\equiv 2-5k\equiv \pmod 5$. You're just running through the cases. Every integer $x$ is one of $0,1,2,3$, or $4$ mod $5$.

Answer (score 3):

For every integer $x$ we have $x\equiv 0,\pm1, \pm2 \pmod 5$ but then we have $x^2\equiv 0,1,-1\pmod 5$. So if $2-5k = x^2$ for some integers $x$ and $k$, we would have $$x^2 \equiv 2\pmod 5$$ A contradiction.

Comment: Why do we have x ≡ 0, ±1, ±2(mod5)?

Comment: It the same as $0,\pm1,\pm2 \equiv 0,1,4,2,3 \pmod 5$ .

Answer (score 2):

Note than any number $n$ ends with the ones digits $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$. If we square $n$, we multiply the one digits, and do some carrying to get $0,1,4,5,6,9$ as the one digits of $n^2$. Now let's examine the ones digits of $2-5k$ for various values of $k$. For $k=0$, ones digit is $2$, however a square doesn't end in $2$ as we have shown before. For $k=-1$ we have $2+5 =7$, but a square can't end in $7$. For $k=-2$ we have $2+10 = 12$, which ends in $2$, but we can't have it end in $2$. Notice that every time we increase $k$ by $1$, the ones digit switches from $2$ to $7$ or $7$ to $2$. This is because you are only adding $5$ each time, thus if you add it to $2$ it becomes $7$, and if you add it to $7$ you get $12$ which has units digit $2$. Since we have shown that a series will switch between $2,7$ as the ones digits if it adds $5$ each time and we have shown that the base cases have $2,7$ as units digits, we have proven that $2-5k$ will always end in $2,7$ (assuming it is positive). However, a square cannot end in $2,7$, thus $2-5k$ can never be a square.

Comment: "and do some carrying to get $0,1,4,9$ as the one digits of $n^2$": so what about $4^2=16$ having a $6$ for its one's digit? Or $5^2=25$ having a $5$?

Comment: Fixed @alex.jordan